# jQuery adding self-closed DIV tag in IE8

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer-8, innerhtml

The code below sets up an edit interface from the data that is already on the form, which works fine. Except that according to [this msdn article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms533897%28VS.85%29.aspx), any tag that is self closed (ex: `<div />`) does not have an innerhtml property. This makes it so my personal jscript calendar library chokes on the innerHTML assignment to the div that is being created.

```
fields.find("p[item][type='Calendar']").each(function() {
            index++;
            var currentText = $(this).html();
            $(this).html("<input id=\"calInput" + index + "\" type=\"text\" value=\"" + currentText + "\" /><div id=\"cal" + index + "\"></div>");
            myFactory.newCalendar("cal" + index, "calInput" + index);
        });
```

How can I force jQuery to use the html I've outlined below instead of creating the self-closed div?

Edit: The html code that results from the above is:

```
<div id="cal2" style="" class="jcalStyle hide"/>
```

I need it to be:

```
<div id="cal2" style="" class="jcalStyle hide"></div>
```

Edit 2:

Firefox is generating the HTML properly. I don't know why IE8 is self-closing (voiding?) the div.

Comment: a div tag is required to have a closing tag: http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/struct/global.html#edef-DIV

Comment: @Davin - I'm aware. I'm not the reason the div tag isn't closed. jQuery appears to be generating the html that way.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The article isn't saying that self-closing tags have no `innerHTML`. It's saying that tags with the *empty* content model ([*void elements*](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/Overview.html#void-elements), in spec-speak, like `img`) don't have it.

Note also that in HTML, `div` cannot be written `<div/>` ([reference](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/Overview.html#start-tags)). It must be written `<div></div>`. Many, many tools (jQuery, for instance) let you play fast and loose with the rules, but don't worry, jQuery isn't actually *adding* that tag to your page markup (it's adding the element to the DOM, which is a different thing entirely). That `<element/>` syntax is *only* allowed on void elements (like `img`) and foreign elements (like SVG stuff).

Comment: "The innerHTML property is valid for both block and inline elements. By definition, elements that do not have both an opening and closing tag cannot have an innerHTML property." And the error I'm getting (a generic one with no info) is similar to errors received from attempting to write to readonly elements.

Comment: @C Bauer: Yes. But `div` **does** have an opening and closing tag. When they say *"...elements that do not have both an opening and closing tag"* they're talking about how the element is *specified*, not how you're writing it. I can't tell you what the error is about, you haven't shown us your `newCalendar` code.

Comment: @TJ - Yeah, but the resulting code doesn't have a closing tag, it's self closed. See the edit above.

Comment: @C Bauer: jQuery's modifications to your DOM don't result in HTML code. They result in DOM modifications. You may be using a tool that shows you the DOM using HTML-like syntax, but if so, the error is in the tool showing you that. And again, even if the `div` were (invalidly) written `<div/>`, it would have an `innerHTML` property regardless.

Comment: @TJ - Well, I'm using the IE8 developer tools. Another thing to not trust Microsoft with I guess.

Comment: @C Bauer: LOL! Yeah, they're using a kind of shorthand there. :-) FYI, just making absolutely sure: http://jsbin.com/owepu (HTML5) and http://jsbin.com/owepu/3 (XHTML) In both cases, the invalid self-closing tag has an `innerHTML` property.

Comment: @C Bauer: And just in case jQuery was protecting us from ourselves (it does that): http://jsbin.com/igeyu3 (HTML) and http://jsbin.com/igeyu3/2 (XHTML). (Although I don't think JSBin will properly serve XHTML.)